# Calling a method from another method (java)

Tags: java, boolean

I started learning java on my own a few weeks back and I keep running up to the same basic problem, where I can't call a method from another method in the same class. I either get a "symbol not found" error (I think because the method is out scope or the method just doesn't work anymore. The following code is part of a [java exercise](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3f_OOPExercises.html#zz-1.10) for creating a calender sort of a programme. I'll use the // in code  commentaries to indicate, where exactly is the problem.

```
public class MyDate {
private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
private static String[] strMonths = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
"Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};

private static String[] strDays = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

private static int[] daysInMonths = {31, 28, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) { // This is the first method, which works fine 
// when being called from the main method.
    if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    };

public static boolean isLeapYear; // I put this declaration in, because I got 
// "symbol not found" errors, when referencing the method from the second method. 
// I'm guessing it partially invalidates the first declaration.
public static boolean isValidDate(int year, int month, int day) { // The second method
    if ((year >= 1 ) && (year <= 9999)){
        if ((month >= 0) && (month <= 11)) {
            if ((day >= 1) && ((month == 0) || (month == 2) || (month == 4) || (month == 6) 
|| (month == 7) || (month == 9) || (month == 11)) && (day <= 31)) {
                return true;
            }  
            else if ((day >= 1) && ((month == 3) || (month == 5) || (month == 8) 
|| (month == 10) && (day <= 30))) {
                return true;
            } 
            else if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)){ 
// Code from the first method (above), which I would like to replace with just a reference 
// to the first method (for instance (isLeapYear = true)), 
// but it doesn't work the same as the code above (or at all).
                if ((month == 1) && (day == 29)) {
                    return true;
                } 
                else
                    if ((day >= 1) && ((month == 1) && (day <= 28))) {
                    return true;
                    } 
                    else {
                        return false;
                        }



            }           
        }
    }
    return isValidDate; }
```

For reference, the method isLeapYear works as it's supposed to, when testing it with this main method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(isLeapYear(1900));  // false
  System.out.println(isLeapYear(2000));  // true
  System.out.println(isLeapYear(2011));  // false
  System.out.println(isLeapYear(2012));  // true
   }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `isLeapYear(year)` is how you call it.

Comment: please show the code that actually generates the error. what you have right now doesn't actually show a call to isLeapYear except from main (which is not an issue). also, leave the semicolon off the end of your method definition.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `public static boolean isLeapYear;` from your code and every time you need to call a function, in this case `public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) { ..}` you must use a parenthesis to let the compiler know that you are actually calling a function there.

In this case you should go with `isLeapYear(year)`

and then `if (isLeapYear(year)) { .. } else {..}`

Answer (score 0):

Given package name of `MyApplication` (substitute your package name in each place this one occurs below) `import` `isLeapYear` as shown below.

```
package MyApplication;

public class MyDate {

public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) { // This is the first method, which works fine 
// when being called from the main method.
    if (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    };

}
```

Main class:

```
package MyApplication;

import static MyApplication.MyDate.isLeapYear;

public class NewClass{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
  {
    System.out.println(isLeapYear(1900));  // false
    System.out.println(isLeapYear(2000));  // true
    System.out.println(isLeapYear(2011));  // false
    System.out.println(isLeapYear(2012));     
  }
}
```